# Background-image 1px shift

Tags: html, css

I'm developing on of my first websites and I'm experiencing a problem with a pixel shifting place.

Here is my html:

```
 <section class="hero-section text-center">

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Monetize Your Content</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <button class="btn btncta"><a href="#">Start Your <strong>Free</strong> Trial</a></button>
    <p class="small">Available On</p>
    <i class="fa fa-windows fa-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-apple fa-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-linux fa-2x"></i>
  </div>

</section>

<section id="features">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <div class="feature-inner">
        <i class="fa fa-search fa-4x "></i>
        <h3>Search Anywhere</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p class="learnmore-a">Learn More ></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS (not the whole thing):

```
.hero-section{
    padding: 100px 0 70px 0;
    background: @color-herosec url('../images/hero_bg.png') no-repeat center bottom;
    width:100%;
 }

#features{

     background: url(../images/separator-inverted.png) no-repeat top center, url(../images/separator.png) no-repeat bottom center;
     padding:50px 10px 50px 10px;
}
```

The result is supposed to be this one, but without that 1px shift on those separators:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zbxbhr1iqsz6b6j/Screenshot%202014-10-01%2021.02.28.png?dl=0

I've tried this fix :

```
html {
    margin-left: -1px;
    overflow-Y: scroll;
}
```

But the result is still a shifted background image (less shifted but still displaced):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mxklaez760vvbmk/Screenshot%202014-10-01%2021.04.45.png?dl=0

Anyone know how to fix this strange bug?

I've seen stuff about the div width and image width, but I haven't grasped it nor has it worked.

My warmest regards

Comment: Have you reset your css first? May this help you: http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: Oh let me see if that works, i only used modernizr

Comment: just in case, make sure your background image is EXACTLY cut. If it has 1px left at one of its sides, you'll have that issue

Comment: at the top of your css put `*{margin: 0 0;}` if you have a slight margin on the very edge of the page, which is what i think is the issue

Comment: Fabio always ready to help xD, the image is perfectly cut mate. @aldanux , the reset didn't work mate.

Comment: @Parody ,that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there are many possibilities and answers to your problem, and I tried in a local bootstrap version and it worked fine. It seems you have something else affecting the output, so here's yet another way to achieve what you want:

1) cut the image as a full circle (not half circle as you have now), make it transparent, so the circle will have the center blue and the outer part in white, just as you have
2) add a div between your top and bottom div (note that this method can be used for navigational purposes as well). add a class name to it.
3) let's assume your circle image is 100px and your div name is "interstitial", so your CSS would be:

```
.interstitial{width:100%; height:100px; background:transparent url(circle.png) no-repeat 50%; top:-50px}
```

and there you go, a bulletproof cross browser method to have that separator work between two divs.

However, you may find that you'll end with a full circle in your final element (I don't know if you will continue using it or not), so if you plan to use it in more divs, then you want to "cut" it, simply change the div name to (say) interstitial2 and then:

```
.interstitial2{width:100%; height:100px; background:transparent url(circle.png) no-repeat top center; top:-50px}
```

yes, it's a bit more convoluted than the straight solution I gave you yesterday, but well, since you're having problems, here you have a problem free solution.

Comment: That worked mate. Gives a little bit more work for sure, but worth it. Again, you saved my project ahah Thanks mate

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that the method I used only shifts on specific sizes. If I resize the windows a bit smaller than it looks fine. With this method there isn't really a problem

Comment: Actually, it didn't work at first. I had to use a negative margin instead of top:50px, because that wasn't moving the circle.